# missing row label in print layout when columns are wider than page

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have a paginated report that summarizes various categories (the rows), by date (columns). The report works correctly for grouping and page breaks. My problem starts when the number of dates exceeds the width of the page in Print Layout mode. What property am I not setting correctly?
thank you in advance for any assistance.

This is the report design:

[image]

When I run the report, the layout is correct

[image]

When I view in Print Layout mode, the first page is correct but the second page loses the row categories.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you probably just need to adjust the report's page width and (probably) the body width. Make sure the body width is no wider than page width minus the sum of the left and right margins.

Comment: If I adjust the page width then the report won't fit on a Letter size page, portrait mode. I could go landscape mode but that still doesn't solve the problem. The user will have the ability to select a date range so multiple wide pages is something I have to account for.

Comment: Apologies, that will teach me to read question fully! Answer added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the tablix control and then set the `RepeatRowHeaders` property to `True`.

[image]

---

Update after looking at RDL

---

I cannot work out why your report is not working (limited time to investigate). However, I removed the matrix control and just created it from scratch, I did not do anything else and, other that a bit of formatting that I didn't replicate, it works as expected.

This GIF shows you your version on the left vs the version I edited on the right

[image]

I can't share the revised version directly so if you can provide a dropbox folder that I can update, I can send you the revised RDL back. If not I'll send it from my personal account later somehow.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I set the property and is still give the same result.

Comment: That's odd. I just built a test report to try this out and it worked as expected. To remove the possibility of a problem caused by you trying things out, can you create a new report, add your matrix and set the property without changing anything else and see if you still get the issue.

Comment: I created a simple report and still can't get the row headings to appear. Could it be due to the way I'm grouping the data?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you show a small sample of data, then show the report design but with the tablix selected so I can see the grouping indicators on the left edge and then, based on the sample data, explain how you are grouping (it is probably obvious but just in case there is something odd going on). I've just tested with two row groups and it works as expected.

Comment: I put sample data and the rdl in  
[dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0z6swjduqowtffd/AAACaUmVY5ZqQvd5NQaG5IVOa?dl=0)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that (not easily). I don't have SSRS for Power BI setup. This won't affect the issue you are seeing but makes it hard for me to reproduce your data. If you can export the results of the dataset query into a csv so it includes all the data the report design requires, then I can take alook when I get a chance.

Comment: I uploaded an RDL test.rdl that has the test data manually entered. Thank you in advance for all of your assistance.

Comment: I've updated the answer only to show it's working, read the text around the edit in the answer and I'll see if I can get the revised RDL back to you.

Comment: here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/c4e48vrmccelww44d10dx/h?dl=0&rlkey=7trnztm3if3mgof1h7rmqq978) with edit rights

Comment: I've uploaded the revised rdl. Literally all I did was delete the existing matrix, add a new one, drag and drop the identifier into the row placeholder, closedat into the column placeholder and parts margin into the data placeholder. I then added the extra rows (insert row inside group - below) for the remaining margin fields and set the repeat row headers property to true. Nothing more...